# CXF. How to get static XML

Tags: java, xml, cxf

I have cfx web service that respond to client my objects. But in some cases I have to send static xml-encoded data, that I read from a stream. How could I do this avoiding marshalling/unmarshalling process

Comment: I have no idea how to do this. Except of unmarshall given xml to my object and return it in endpont.

Comment: I have not used this feature, but you might want to look into the "Redirecting requests and serving the static content" section of the CXF [Servlet Transport](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html) documentation.